# Status bar of activity_main is darker compared to other activities in my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I have a weird problem with my app, the toolbar of my app is darker than other activities I have, I am not sure why exactly this is happening, could someone help me out with this, maybe I have done something wrong with the toolbar code, its not exactly a problem, its just that its looks ugly. Any expert guidance will be highly appreciated. Please let me know, if I have formatted the question wrong, I want to get better at this.

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
tools:context="com.fayaz.uniabex.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_white_18dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFab"/>
```

[image: The toolbar doesn't seem right]
The toolbar doesn't seem right

[image: Correct one]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it happens because of `AppBarLayout`'s elevation.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    ...
    app:elevation="0dp">
```

Note that set `app:elevation` to zero, not `android:elevation`.

Comment: Hi @6londe, thanks for the quick response, right now I am at work, I will update you once I reach home and fix this.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked exactly like you mentioned!